# Jenkins, bit bucket and Vagrant : cannot log in git

Tags: git, symfony, ssh, jenkins

I want to integrate Jenkins to my Symfony 2 project, which is on a BitBucket repository.

I installed Jenkins on my Vagrant virtual machine, and then I configure a job.

So, in Source Code Management, I selected Git, and set the BitBucket SSH url in "Repository URL" (git@bitbucket.org:me/myproject.git). Then, logged as jenkins in my Vagrant box, I generated a SSH key, and I copied the id_rsa.pub in a new SSH Public Key in BitBucket. I added this key as credidential in my Jenkins job git configuration (with username as my BitBucket username).

Jenkins displays me this error when I try to build the project:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api/workspace
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myproject.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
FATAL: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myproject.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myproject.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:625)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:847)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:872)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1411)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:651)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1670)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening ?
Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the remote server denied your pubic key. The logs are telling you that => `stderr: Permission denied (publickey).`

Do this, head to `~/.ssh` Create a file called `config` and add the following, ensure the values reflect your personal setup.

```
Host bitbucket.org
    User myuser
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then re-run.

Comment: Thanks ! But why ? What does this tiny file changes ?

Comment: If you do not have this file, during `ssh`, Linux/Unix will pick up the `id_rsa` or `id_dsa` key under `~/.ssh` and try to SSH with them. In the event you have multiple public keys or the keys are in a different location, once you provide the `~/.ssh/config` the ssh program will pick up the keys based on that config. All the config file above states is for bitbucket.org use the key in the location mentioned. The only thing I can assume is during `ssh` the wrong keys are being picked up, you can confirm this by removing the config file and running `ssh -v bitbucket.org`.